# Can't return value in Golang

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and I dont get why I can't return a value. I think it's a small mistake. I just want to return a string I picked in a DB.

```
func myFunction() string {

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT my_string ORDER BY agents_count ASC LIMIT 1;")
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var my_string string

        if err := rows.Scan(&my_string); err != nil {
            logger.Fatal(err)
        }
        
        logger.Info("Result : ", my_string)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }

    return my_string
}
```

Any idea ? What is my mistake ?

Comment: What does it mean _"I can't return"_? Also note `logger.Fatal()` may terminate your app (don't know which logger you're using).

Comment: @icza thanks for your answer ! I just get `./my_progr.go:71:12: undefined: my_string`, and line 71 matches the `return` line. But by variable is defined just above and I'm even able to print it.

Comment: my_string is declared in the for loop, so the for loop is its scope. It doesn't exist outside of its scope, by definition.

Comment: @Peter i am not sure what is your programming background but this is how GO works. For loop has its own scope so you need declare your variables outside of it to use them later on

Comment: @Sam you seem to have misunderstood Peter's comment. Or maybe you just wanted to rephrase what he said?

Comment: @mkopriva but he wants to return undefined value. So the return should be in for loop. You can not return undefined value

Comment: @Sam returning from the loop is a valid approach, I didn't say anything to the contrary, and neither did Peter. I was just trying to point out that your previous comment seems only to re-state what Peter's comment already states, even though you addressed it to Peter as though he made a mistake. If I am the one who misunderstood then I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting a single row as you are doing (using `LIMIT 1`), instead of [`Query`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17#DB.Query) you should use the [`QueryRow`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17#DB.QueryRow) method or, the newer, [`QueryRowContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17#DB.QueryRowContext) method.

```golang
func myFunction() string {
    var my_string string
    
    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT my_string ORDER BY agents_count ASC LIMIT 1;")
    if err := row.Scan(&my_string); err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    return my_string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move my_string to outer loop

```
func myFunction() string {

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT my_string ORDER BY agents_count ASC LIMIT 1;")
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    var my_string string

    for rows.Next() {

        if err := rows.Scan(&my_string); err != nil {
            logger.Fatal(err)
        }
        
        logger.Info("Result : ", my_string)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }

    return my_string
}
```